# Do you need to reattach an in app purchase (IAP) to a version of your app after that app version is rejected?

Tags: iphone, ios, submission, in-app-purchase

After creating and testing my first IAP in iTunesConnect, I created a new app version and connected it to the IAP (as you must with it being the first one).

The binary for the app version I submitted was rejected, so I corrected the issue and went to resubmit however I do not see the IAP section appearing in the app version details.  I have sections for version information, meatadata and uploads, app review information, and EULA, but not for in-app purchase.  Is there something I'm missing?  Does an IAP need to be "reattached" to a version after a rejection to the binary (not the IAP), or does the IAP remain connected to the version and simply get reviewed with the resubmitted binary?  It's confusing that it is not listed on the Version Details page at all, which is why I wanted to reach out for some help before waiting through the entire review process...

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in case someone stumbles upon this in the same situation, if you added the IAP when you first created the version, you're all set.  No need to add it again if your first submission gets rejected.  To confirm, your IAP should switch over to "In Review" fairly soon after the resubmission (even while your binary sits in "Waiting for Review")

Comment: So when my first binary gets rejected and my in-app purchases to Developer Action needed, I can just create a second, new binary and upload it to iTunes Connect and also just resave my in-app purchases to make them go into the state of waiting for review? I didnt link my second app to the in-app purchases created with my first binary. Is this fine (YES/NO)?

Answer (score 0):

Finish the process of preparing to upload. Make sure you have clicked the Ready to Upload Binary button (I always forget that step). You will then be able to see the Manage In-App Purchases button for that app.

Comment: Hey Matt.  So, when I first created the version, I know that I selected the IAP. However, the first version I uploaded was rejected.  Was I supposed to do this again for the resubmitted version? As in, I after the rejection when I clicked "Ready to Upload" for the new version, the menu to add IAPs to the version would have displayed again? I wasn't looking for this, so I actually submitted the second version without doing it and it has been waiting for review since yesterday morning. If you're certain, though, I'll reject it and resubmit, this time being on the lookout for the menu to reappear

Comment: No, I wouldn't touch it at this point - I've never gone through the *exact* scenario you're describing.

Comment: Another thought: If you've already submitted the binary, you should be able to *see* whether it has the in-app purchase associated with it.

Comment: Yeah, kind of interesting.  In the version details of the app, I don't see the IAP anywhere (again, I did attach it the first time I created the version before I ever changed it to "Ready to Upload" to submit the first, rejected version).  If I go to the "Manage IAP Screen" menu (not under the specific version, but under the app itself), the IAP does show its status as "In Review."  I plan on leaving the binary alone, but I did shoot a follow-up email to Apple just to verify - I'll let you know what they say.

Comment: Hi @tonyd did you ever get a response from Apple? My scenario is similar, I created and added the IAP to my app, but then had to reject the app. Now my app is in "Ready to Upload Binary" state but the IAP is not available to select anywhere in the metadata. The IAP is in "Waiting for Review" state.

Comment: @Hahnemann For me, there was no reason to do anything else.  Simply re-upload your new version and your IAP should get reviewed with the binary (mine did).  Also, that status of my IAP soon changed over to "In Review" after I re-uploaded the new version.